# Why does 'adb.exe devices' not see my phone on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, adb

I have USB Debugging & File Transfer both enabled on my phone (Blackview A80Pro) and I have installed the USB driver for my phone as recommended by Blackview. But though 'adb.exe version' shows the version, 'adb.exe devices' does not show my phone on Windows 10. Interestingly, Ubuntu 20.04 does see my phone using a Linux version of adb!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Make sure your device is not connected as a media device, on the phone enable Developer tools and USB Debugging.

Comment: @harrymc Exactly what I suggested at AU where the original question was posted.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I found the [original post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950829/adb-finds-no-devices-and-mtp-does-not-work). It has a nice [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863587/adb-device-list-doesnt-show-phone) which suggests some solutions. It would be useful for the poster to include in his question what he tried from that link, and why it didn't work.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The post you referred to is about Ubuntu not finding the phone. My question is about Windows 10 not finding the phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does 'adb.exe devices' not show my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/245780/why-does-adb-exe-devices-not-show-my-phone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adb.exe 1.0.40 needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395961/adb-exe-1-0-40-needed)

Comment: For some makes/models you may need to change the USB connection to different modes, rather than the default "File Transfer".  I've had devices that required you to switch to PIP and one that required MIDI before the insecure verification prompt would push to mobile notifications, from there you hit confirm and it should work.  Also, you may want to double check you have the latest version of ADB / fastboot installed, note that you might have to update them through SDK or find a pre-compiled on XDA.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does 'adb.exe devices' not see my phone on Windows 10?

Because you did not install adb drivers in correct manner.

edit: your original question is about Windows 10 Virtual Machine. in addition to the links shared you must therefore enable usb passthrough

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads